# What is a computational problem?

Tags: computability, terminology

I'm reading Sipser's "introduction to the theory of computation" book. Even though in many places the phrase "computational problem" appears there is no definition of it. How is it defined?

Some other questions I thought about when trying the understand the nature of a "computational problem":

Are there mathematical problems which are not computational problems? (I do not mean undecidable problems since undecidable problems are still computational problems that cannot be solved by computers). Or every mathematical problem is also a computational problem? In general, is there a difference between a mathematical problem and a computational problem.

Comment: Not every concept has a formal definition. Sipser's textbook is not a philosophical tract, and I suggest not reading too much into these terms.

Comment: A computational problem is a problem in which we want to compute something.

Comment: In a way you are right, every mathematical statement should be provable by formal computation from axioms (but for Gödel's limitations). When they say computational, they mean that you want *an explicit algorithm*.